# Mocking a partial (exception throwing) function

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito, specs2

I'm writing a unit test using Mockito and Specs 2 in Scala. I have a class `Foo` with a method `bar` which is partially defined in the domain of its input parameter `x`. If the result is not defined for the given input value an `FooException` is thrown:

```
public abstract class Foo {
  public abstract int bar(String x) throws FooException;
}

public class FooException extends Exception {}
```

Now I'm trying to create a mock using Mockito. I wish to specify that bar only returns a result for `x` and `y` and throws an exception otherwise:

```
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import org.specs2.mock.Mockito
import org.mockito.Matchers._

class FooTest extends Specification with Mockito {

   val foo = mock[Foo]
   foo.bar("x") returns 1
   foo.bar("y") returns 2
   foo.bar(anyString) throws mock[FooException]

   "Foo.bar()" should {
       "return an integer for x" in {
           foo.bar("x") must be equalTo(1)
       }

      "throw an exception for z" in {
           foo.bar("z") must throwA[FooException]
      }
   }
}
```

Unfortunately, this test fails. How do I write my mock in such a way that my tests pass?

**Update**

The tests fail because an exception is thrown at runtime. The code above results in:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
[error] Could not run test FooTest: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

If I change the order, as suggested in one of the answers, I get the following stack trace:

```
[error] Could not create an instance of FooTest
[error]   caused by java.lang.Exception: Could not instantiate class FooTest: null
[error]   org.specs2.reflect.Classes$class.tryToCreateObjectEither(Classes.scala:93)
[error]   org.specs2.reflect.Classes$.tryToCreateObjectEither(Classes.scala:207)
[error]   org.specs2.specification.SpecificationStructure$$anonfun$createSpecificationEither$2.apply(BaseSpecification.scala:119)
[error]   org.specs2.specification.SpecificationStructure$$anonfun$createSpecificationEither$2.apply(BaseSpecification.scala:119)
[error]   scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
[error]   org.specs2.specification.SpecificationStructure$.createSpecificationEither(BaseSpecification.scala:119)
[error]   org.specs2.runner.SbtRunner.org$specs2$runner$SbtRunner$$specificationRun(SbtRunner.scala:73)
[error]   org.specs2.runner.SbtRunner$$anonfun$newTask$1$$anon$5.execute(SbtRunner.scala:59)
[error]   sbt.TestRunner.runTest$1(TestFramework.scala:84)
[error]   sbt.TestRunner.run(TestFramework.scala:94)
[error]   sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(TestFramework.scala:219)
[error]   sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(TestFramework.scala:219)
[error]   sbt.TestFramework$.sbt$TestFramework$$withContextLoader(TestFramework.scala:207)
[error]   sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(TestFramework.scala:219)
[error]   sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(TestFramework.scala:219)
[error]   sbt.TestFunction.apply(TestFramework.scala:224)
[error]   sbt.Tests$$anonfun$7.apply(Tests.scala:196)
[error]   sbt.Tests$$anonfun$7.apply(Tests.scala:196)
[error]   sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(System.scala:45)
[error]   sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(System.scala:45)
[error]   sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
[error]   sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
[error]   sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
[error]   sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
[error]   sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
[error]   sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
[error]   sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
[error]   sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
[error]   sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
[error]   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
[error]   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
[error]   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
[error]   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
[error]   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
[error]   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[error]   caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: "this test fails" can you explain how it fails?

Comment: Use a `lazy val` instead of a `val`: `lazy val foo = mock[Foo]`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the order of your stubbing around.  Stub the generalized behavior first (anyString) and then add more specific behaviors after that.  So do this:

```
val foo = mock[Foo]
foo.bar(anyString) throws mock[FooException]
foo.bar("x") returns 1
foo.bar("y") returns 2
```

Comment: I tried your approach before, however this results in a runtime exception as well. I updated the original question with the stack trace.

Answer (score -1):

You could set up a callback on the mock:

```
  val foo = mock[Foo]
  foo.bar(anyString) answers (derp => {
    derp match {
      case "x" => 1
      case "y" => 2
      case _ => throw mock[FooException]
    }
  })
```

There are some more details in the [specs2 documentation](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Matchers.html#Mock+expectations).

Comment: Thanks, this works! Could some one explain why this answer is down voted?

Comment: Could be that there is a more elegant way of writing this, the anyString feels redundant... also might be reservations to adding logic to a mock in the first place. Too bad the down voter did not speak up.